# Why doesn't pattern matching on a tuple using my active patterns work?

Tags: f#

Here are the active patterns I've defined along with my function that tries to do pattern matching:

```
let (|Left|)     i = i = 0
let (|Top|)      j = j = 0
let (|Right|)  w i = i = w - 1
let (|Bottom|) h j = j = h - 1

let test w h (i, j) =
    match i, j with
    | (Left   , Top     ) -> 1
    | (Left   , Bottom h) -> 2
    | (Right w, Top     ) -> 3
    | (Right w, Bottom h) -> 4
    | (_      , _       ) -> 5
```

I expected this to match, for example, `(0, 0)` with `(Left, Top)` and `(99, 99)` with `(Right 100, Bottom 100)`. Instead, it's not even compiling (one of the errors is "FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'bool' but here has type 'unit'").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [partial active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns#partial-active-patterns) for this:

```ml
let (|Left|_|)     i = if i = 0 then Some Left else None
let (|Top|_|)      j = if j = 0 then Some Top else None
let (|Right|_|)  w i = if i = w - 1 then Some Right else None
let (|Bottom|_|) h j = if j = h - 1 then Some Bottom else None

let test w h (i, j) =
    match i, j with
    | (Left   , Top     ) -> 1
    | (Left   , Bottom h) -> 2
    | (Right w, Top     ) -> 3
    | (Right w, Bottom h) -> 4
    | (_      , _       ) -> 5

test 100 100 (0, 0)   |> printfn "%A"   // (Left, Top)     -> 1
test 100 100 (99, 99) |> printfn "%A"   // (Right, Bottom) -> 4
```

Comment: Thanks! I would have never figured that out on my own. I haven't seen examples like this.

Comment: @redcurry Look into official Docs for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns